# Splitting a word's letters into individual variables with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to split a word into individual letters with each letter being a different variable?

For example:

```
Hello 
Would be 
1 = H
2 = e
3 = l
4 = l
5 = o
```

I'm looking for the simplest way to do this.

Comment: I think that's the reason why the arrays were made.

Comment: Do you mean splitting the string into an array of characters?

Comment: a string is an array,  you can address it   "blah"[1]

Comment: You can access the string like an array and this gives you one character at a time...

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of replies.. @mikevelazco i don't want to return A [1] because if the user entered numbers it would be 1 [1]. Besides, I'd prefer to but them into variables so I can easily compare them.

Comment: @Hkessel1 something sounds odd about what you are trying to do, nothing is stopping you putting things in variables if you need to by using array addressing, but you shouldn't need too many,  there maybe a much better way to solve your bigger problem

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This thing that you're trying to do could result as low performance code/hard to maintain or too complicated code. I'm not saying not to do, but you should think about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want each letter in individual objects you can make use of [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
let [a,b,c,d,e] = "hello"
console.log(a, b, c, d, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Hkessel1,

Did you try spread operator in ES6? I am not sure whether this solves your problem?

let s= "Hello";

console.log(...s);

Answer (score -1):

just index through the string.

```
var str = "Hello";

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    var myVar = str[i]; // get my variable 
    // do something with it.
}
```

Comment: you don't need to split a string, it's array addressable

Answer (score -2):

Just use a variable as below:

```
var test="Hello";
```

Then test[0] means H

test[1] is e

and so on

Answer (score -2):

you can in es6, do

```
var a,b,c
[a,b,c] = "Hello"
console.log(a,b,c)
```

but you can't dynamically create the variables, just use an array in that case.